# Загрузка формы программы при условии наличии файла по указанному пути

Tags: c#, winforms

Каким образом можно организовать проверку на наличие файла при загрузке формы?
Если файл существует по указанному пути в программе, то окно загружается в противном случае появляется окошко с предупреждением, что файла нет и программа не может работать. 
Я пробовал поиграться с File.Exist в методе Form(), окошко появляется в котором указанно, что файл требуется но программа спокойно стартует.
В моем случае, мне требуется проверка наличия шрифта. И если шрифт есть в папке Fonts, то программа работает. Если нет, то пишет ошибку и рекомендацию к установке шрифта.
Привожу пример кода который я пытался прикрутить.

```
public Form1()
    {
        string path = @"C:\\Windows\\Font\\SelfmadeFont";
        string fontname = "SelfmadeFont";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Данного шрифта нет в системе. Для корректной работы программы пожалуйста установите шрифт" + fontname);
        }

    }
```

Собственно программа сначала показывает мне предупреждение и потом появляется просто пустая форма которую я даже не создавал.

Comment: Ну, мне кажется, что всё правильно: программа запущена, но форма не инициализирована.  Используйте в теле else метод this.Close(), как вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если реализовывать проверку в конструкторе формы, то логично предположить что форма уже создается (и только после этого срабатывает конструктор и проверка на наличие файла).
Следовательно пути решения два. Или установить проверку ДО загрузки формы. То есть в файле Program.
Либо организовать проверку в форме, но после отрицательного результата просто выйти из приложения.
Можно через this.Close(), это закрывает текущую форму (и если в приложении она одна, то закроется все приложение, в противном случае могут быть глюки).
Либо через: Environment.Exit(0), это гарантированное закрытие приложения.
В данном случае надо вставить любую строку после MessageBox.

Comment: Добавил после Меседжбокса Environment.Exit(0). Программа на старте выдает ошибку, об отсутствии шрифта. Хотя шрифт в системе есть.

Comment: А это уже совсем другая история. Возможно он просто не видит сей шрифт. Собственно у файла еще разрешение есть. То есть не: @"C:\\Windows\\Font\\SelfmadeFont", а @"C:\\Windows\\Font\\SelfmadeFont.ttf". Ну или как то так.

Comment: Кстати, еще нюанс. Строка адреса указана неправильно. Надо ИЛИ использовать @, ИЛИ экранирование слешей. То есть или: string path = @"C:\Windows\Font\SelfmadeFont.ttf"; или string path = "C:\\Windows\\Font\\SelfmadeFont.ttf";

Comment: Все разобрался:)
Неправильно указал папку с шрифтами. В ссылку указал Font, а папка на самом деле Fonts. Спасибо за помощь:)